# What is the percentage of these numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, statistics

Consider the numbers $N$ of the form:

$2580\cdot x + 2236\cdot y$, with $x$ and $y$ nonnegative integers.

I have to calculate the density of these numbers below $10^5$.

I mean suppose $\rho (10^5)$ is the number of $N$'s below $10^5$.

Which is the value of  $\frac{\rho(10^5)}{10^5}$?

Is the brute force approach useful with a calculator?

$\gcd(2580,2236)=172$

Does it mean that roughly $1/172$ of nonnegative integers below $10^5$ has that form?

Now a question a bit harder:

what percentage of the $N$'s are also congruent to $10^m\pmod {41}$? Is this equivalent to ask what percentage of the multiples of $172$ are congruent to $10^m\pmod {41}$, for some positive $m$?

Comment: Are you familiar with number theory and Bezouts lemma?  Brute force is *not* the way, but you can come up with a specific formula for which numbers are and are not of this form.

Comment: @fleablood a bit yes with bezous lemma

Comment: So ...... every number of the form $2580x + 2236y$ will be ... what?  And every number that is ... what.... can be written in the form $2580x + 2236y$?

Answer (score 1):

Bezout's Lemma.  Every number of the form $2580x + 2236y$ is a multiple of $\gcd(2580,2236) =172$.  And every multiple of $172$ can be written of the forms $2580x + 2236y$.

So $N\in \mathbb Z$ is of the form $2580x + 2236y;x,y \in \mathbb Z\iff N$ is a multiple of $172$.

So you need to figure out what percentage of integers are multiples of $172$.

And $\frac 1{172} \approx 0.5814\%$ of all integers are multiples of $172$.

There are $\lfloor \frac {10^5}{172} \rfloor = 581$ multiples of $172$ less than $10^5$.

....

Okay Okay the second qestion:

One out of $41$ numbers are congruent to $K\pmod {41}$ for any $K$.

And so you want all numbers that are $x \equiv 10^5 \pmod {41}$ and $x \equiv 0 \pmod {172}$.

$\gcd(41,10^5)=1$ so by chinese remainder theorem there is one unique solutions $\pmod{41\cdot 172}$.

So the percentage is $\frac 1{41\cdot 172}=0.03387533875338753387533875338753\%$.

There will be around $\frac {10^5}{41\cdot 172} = 14.18$ such numbers less than $10^5$, so there will be either $14$ or $15$ such numbers.

If $k$ is the smallest such number then all the numbers will be of the form $41*172m + k$ for $m =0...... 13$.  That is $41*172 + k, 41*172*2 + k, 41*172*3 + k,   ..... 41*172*13 + k$.   The next number of the form will be $41*172*14 + k$ and that will be a $15$ potential value if $14*172*14 + k \le 10^5$.

To actually solve these numbers:

$10^2 \equiv 100 \equiv 18\pmod {41}$.  $10^3 \equiv 180\equiv 164+16\equiv 16\pmod {41}$.  $10^4 \equiv 160\equiv -4 \pmod {41}$.   So $10^5\equiv -40\equiv 1 \pmod{41}$.

So we need to solve $x\equiv 1\pmod {41}$ and $x \equiv 0\pmod{172}$.  And $21*41-5*172 =1$ so $-21*41 +1 \equiv 0 \pmod {172}$ and $-21*41 + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod {42}$.

So $k = -21*41 + 41*172+1 = 41*151 + 1$.

And $14*41*172 + 41*1451 + 1 > 10^5$ so there are $14$ such numbers.

Comment: Query specified that $x,y$ are **non-negative**.  Therefore, $(172)$ (for example) is not expressible.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: exactly x and y must be not negative

Comment: for what its worth, I dimly remember that there is a Number Theory theorem that is directly on point here, I just don't know what that theorem is.  If you can find the theorem, then brute force is avoidable.

Comment: @fleablood x and y have to be non-negative

Comment: @user2661923 anyway have you a program to see what is the percentage by brute force?

Comment: No, but I imagine that you could write one in Java or C.  I recommend waiting 24 hours for fleablood or someone else on mathSE to remedy situation.  If no remedy, then I recommend that you write computer program.  If trouble writing computer program, mathSE is **definitely not** the forum for asking for programming help.

Comment: Oh, I could *swear* it said $x,y$ *could* be neg.... look up Froiwhatsit coin problem or the Chicken Nugget (shudder) problem.

Comment: @fleablood yes the answer must be changed if x and y are non negative

Answer (score 0):

The second question

There are $23$ numbers of the form $2580 x + 2236 y,\;x,y\in\mathbb{N};\;x\ge 0,y\ge 0$ less than $10^5$ congruent to $10\bmod 41$, while the  total is $499$.

Percentage is $23/499=4.61\%$

$$\small\{12556,19608,26660,33712,40764,47816,54868,61920,61920,68972,68972,76024,76024,\\\small76024,83076,83076,83076,90128,90128,90128,97180,97180,97180\}$$
whose remainder when divided by $41$ is $10$.

Comment: 2nd question asked for a percentage, so the answer is affected by the answer to the first question.  see my comment to fleablood's answer.  also, you would need to verify that the 14 numbers that you documented can each be generated by non-negative $x,y$.

Comment: @user2661923 You are right! I edited with the new results

Comment: Your answer seems to depend on the denominator being $(499)$, which seems to depend on the answer to the first question.  Remember that I am disputing fleablood's current answer.  Where did your $(499)$ figure come from?  Are you sure that it is accurate?

Comment: $499$ are the numbers I got from $2580x+2236y$ less than $10^5$ with nonnegative $x,y$. It doesn't depend on the old $172$ error

Comment: "...I got from ...".  You got **how**, with a computer program, or by finding the (? obscure ?) Number Theory theorem?  If by theorem, then I suggest that you leave a comment under fleablood's answer giving him the reference so that he can repair his answer.

Comment: @Raffaele so there are 499 numbers of the form 2580x+2236y below 10^5 with x and y nonnegative? for the second question you gave a partial answer because you considered only 10 mod 41, but I asked for 10^m mod 41 for m nonnegative

Comment: @Raffaele I think you have calculated some values twice

Comment: @gondoliere $10^2>41$ and makes no sense looking for numbers that give $100\bmod 41$